# How to combine two defined functions with an if statement that impact two columns (Python-pandas)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function, if-statement

Data: [BL-Flickr-Images_Book](https://github.com/realpython/python-data-cleaning/blob/master/Datasets/BL-Flickr-Images-Book.csv)

I am attempting to clean a column called place of publication.  I notice several have similar values with Place of Publication and Date of Publication in them.

ex:

- pp. 40. G. Bryan & Co: Oxford, 1898
- pp. 40. W. Cann: Plymouth, 1876
- pp. vi. 216. Hatchards: London, 1888

I have created two different functions with if loops to extract the Place and Date of Publication.

```
def clean_dates(item):
  pop=str(item.loc['Place of Publication'])
  dop=str(item.loc['Date of Publication'])

  if pop[0:3] != 'pp.':
    return dop

  elif pop[0:3] == 'pp.':
    character_index_comma = pop.find(',')
    dop = pop[character_index_comma+2:]
  return dop
df['Date of Publication']=df.apply(clean_dates, axis=1)

def clean_pop(item):

  pop=str(item.loc['Place of Publication'])
  dop=str(item.loc['Date of Publication'])

  if pop[0:3] == 'pp.':
    character_index_comma = pop.find(',')
    character_index_colon = pop.find(':')
    pop = pop[character_index_colon+2:character_index_comma]
  return pop

df['Place of Publication']=df.apply(clean_pop, axis=1)
```

This code does work and I no longer get values starting with pp... and the corresponding dates are no longer NaN.  I know that I should be able to combine these codes into one loop.

I have attempted to combine these codes into one.

```
def clean_pop(item):

  pop=str(item.loc['Place of Publication'])
  dop=str(item.loc['Date of Publication'])

  if pop[0:3] != 'pp.':
    return dop, pop

  elif pop[0:3] == 'pp.':
    character_index_comma = pop.find(',')
    character_index_colon = pop.find(':')
    dop = pop[character_index_comma+2:]
    pop = pop[character_index_colon+2:character_index_comma]
  return dop, pop

df['Date of Publication', 'Place of Publication']=df.apply(clean_pop, axis=1)
```

However, this code ends up making no changes to Date of Publication or Place of Publication (I am still getting rows with pp....).  How would I go about combining these two functions?

Comment: Pandas- I have added the information. Thank you.

Comment: The best way is to avoid using a function - use [str.startswith](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html) and [where](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With extra square brackets and the `expand` option, you can make the return values from your combined function fill the original columns.

```
df[["Date of Publication", "Place of Publication"]] = df.apply(clean_pop, axis=1, result_type="expand")
```

But you can clean the columns more quickly using vectorized methods and regular expressions instead of applying a function.

```
df = pd.read_csv("https://github.com/realpython/python-data-cleaning/blob/master/Datasets/BL-Flickr-Images-Book.csv?raw=true")

# select rows where place stars with pp.
starts_pp = df["Place of Publication"].str.startswith("pp.") 

# select the place information in these rows
pop = df.loc[starts_pp, "Place of Publication"]              

# Where place starts with pp., change date to the text after the last comma
df["Date of Publication"].mask(starts_pp, 
                               pop.str.extract(".*, (.*)", expand=False), 
                               inplace=True)

# Where place starts with pp., change place to the text between colon and comma               
df["Place of Publication"].mask(starts_pp, 
                               pop.str.extract(".*[.:] (.*),", expand=False), 
                               inplace=True)
```